# Do screen readers read HTML Spans normally?

Tags: html, screen-readers

i made a login form that has a `div` with a `span` in the middle to separate a login with social networks or email and password, like this:

```
<div>
  <button className="wrap-btn _brand-f">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
    <span className="wrap-btn__text">Facebook</span>
  </button>
  <button className="wrap-btn _brand-a">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faApple} />
    <span className="wrap-btn__text">Apple</span>
  </button>
  <div className="wrap-divider">
    <span className="wrap-divider__span">Or</span>
    <span></span> <!-- This is a line that cuts through "or", merely for styling purposes -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And i was wondering if this is the correct way to use a `span` and if screen readers would read it properly. I thought about using an `hr` but i don't think this would be the correct use for it either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that wouldn't work. As a `span` semantically is well... a piece of nothing (or merely everything you want it to be), this wouldn't be read:

```
<span></span> <!-- This is a line that cuts through "or", merely for styling purposes -->
```

I mean, what do you want the screen reader to read there? There's no text inside your `span`. Better use a `hr`, if you want your separator to be accessible.

Comment: This separator is merely for styling purposes, so i'd like it to go undetected. Thanks for the help!